# Materialize Modal doesn't work on starter template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, modal-dialog, materialize

Recently i switched to materialize (it's based on Bootstrap i guess) and i'm trying to make modal work. it just doesn't show up. the button is there but it triggers nothing. I'm using starter template from Materialize website.

All i did was copy and paste modal code from [Materialize modal page.](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) I put the code in starter template but it doesn't work. i also tested it on another theme based on materialize but that didn't work either.

also jQuery is loaded properly.

edit: it's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Starter Template - Materialize</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row center">
        <button data-target="#modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
      </div>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <!--   Icon Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-image-flash-on"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

            <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-social-group"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">User Experience Focused</h5>

            <p class="light">By utilizing elements and principles of Material Design, we were able to create a framework that incorporates components and animations that provide more feedback to users. Additionally, a single underlying responsive system across all platforms allow for a more unified user experience.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-action-settings"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Easy to work with</h5>

            <p class="light">We have provided detailed documentation as well as specific code examples to help new users get started. We are also always open to feedback and can answer any questions a user may have about Materialize.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="section">

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer orange">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Company Bio</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">We are a team of college students working on this project like it's our full time job. Any amount would help support and continue development on this project and is greatly appreciated.</p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Settings</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      Made by <a class="orange-text text-lighten-3" href="http://materializecss.com">Materialize</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <script> $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

modal code:

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here's a demo of Starter template](http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html)

[Here's download link of template](http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template.zip)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the version *v0.97.8 (October 30th, 2016)* modal plugin has been refactored according to the updates from [github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize). Now, the [initialization](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#initialization) of the plugin is done differently, like in the example below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

---

I think you forgot to attach the plugin to the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

Also change this line `data-target="#modal1"`

```
<button data-target="#modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
```

In to this line `data-target="modal1"`, you inserted `#` by mistake, a loudy error noticed me in console.

```
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
```

See the snippet below for working example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row center">
        <button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
      </div>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <!--   Icon Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-image-flash-on"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

            <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-social-group"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">User Experience Focused</h5>

            <p class="light">By utilizing elements and principles of Material Design, we were able to create a framework that incorporates components and animations that provide more feedback to users. Additionally, a single underlying responsive system across all platforms allow for a more unified user experience.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="mdi-action-settings"></i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Easy to work with</h5>

            <p class="light">We have provided detailed documentation as well as specific code examples to help new users get started. We are also always open to feedback and can answer any questions a user may have about Materialize.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="section">

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer orange">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Company Bio</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">We are a team of college students working on this project like it's our full time job. Any amount would help support and continue development on this project and is greatly appreciated.</p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Settings</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      Made by <a class="orange-text text-lighten-3" href="http://materializecss.com">Materialize</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes. but it doesn't work. see the OP again pls take a look at my index.php. i also attached js to the footer

Comment: @vvvsg did you see my snippet? You did the same?

Comment: i did it in index.html

Comment: Great!! I encountered the same issue. It turns out that the plugin initialization is important!

Answer (score 6):

For updated code you should initialize

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```